# Center- align a row of columns in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap. I have a row with a lot of columns of size 3.

```
<div class= "row1" style = margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto">
<div class = col-md-3" > <!--content--> </div>
<div class = col-md-3" > <!--content--> </div>
<div class = col-md-3" > <!--content--> </div>
<div class = col-md-3" > <!--content--> </div>
<div class = col-md-3" > <!--content--> </div>.
.
.
.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row1{

    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

The image shows how the rendered html looks like:
[image]

I do not want the empty space, and want the columns to center themselves horizontally. Is there a way to do this? I need the size to specifically be 3 (I know it doesn't add up to 12, hence the dilemma). 
All the help is very much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Column**(`col-*-*`) element has `float:left;` by default and you can't align **floated element** so you have to use `display:inline-block;` and [remove the extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which is occurred by `display:inline-block;`.

**CSS:**

```
.row1{
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.row1 .col-md-3{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row1">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <!--content-->
      </div><!--
   --><div class="col-md-3">
        <!--content-->
      </div><!--
   --><div class="col-md-3">
        <!--content-->
      </div><!--
   --><div class="col-md-3">
        <!--content-->
      </div><!--
   --><div class="col-md-3">
      <!--content-->
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @KeshavVasudevan You have to give `float:none;`to column. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 18):

As a rule, great frameworks get improved as time goes by. Bootstrap 4 has a new class *Justify-content-center* which does exactly what you want.

```css
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="border: #0b2e13 1px solid;">Hello Friends!</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="border: #0b2e13 1px solid;">Hello Friends!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```